React form data not passing correctly to PHP on iPhone when using useState
I’ve developed a webpage using React.js to replace an existing WordPress site. The React build files are deployed on the same server as the WordPress site.
The page includes a booking form where I use the POST method to send form data to a WordPress PHP page for processing. The setup works perfectly on most devices, and the submitted data shows up on the PHP page as expected.
However, when submitting the form from an iPhone, only the count fields (adult and child) are passed successfully. Other fields like name and email do not appear in the $_POST array on the PHP side.
Interestingly:
When I hardcode the values into the fetch request, they pass successfully, even on an iPhone.
This issue only occurs when using useState to manage form data.
Why does the data fail to pass when using useState on an iPhone, and how can I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Counts (adult and child) are passed successfully, even when managed with useState.
Other fields (name and email) do not pass when managed with useState.
Hardcoding all values (even name and email) works perfectly on all devices, including iPhones.

Here’s one of the input field-related code snippets


import { useState } from 'react';

const BookingForm = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [surName, setSurName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [adultCount, setAdultCount] = useState(0);
  const [childCount, setChildCount] = useState(0);
  const [infantCount, setInfantCount] = useState(0);
  const [hotelName, setHotelName] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [errorHotel, setErrorHotel] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  const handleHotelChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setHotelName(value);
    if (value.trim() === '' && packages.tourTypeId !== 3) {
      setErrorHotel('Hotel name required!');
    } else {
      setErrorHotel('');
    }
  };
  }

  return (
   <form
          ref={tourDataFormRef}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          method='post'
          name='frm'
          id='bookingform'
          action={site_url('/request-summary')}
        >
      <input
        id="hotel-name"
        name="hotel_name"
        type="text"
        value={hotelName}
        onChange={handleHotelChange}
        className="w-full px-1 py-1 border rounded-md cursor-pointer border-body border-opacity-30 placeholder:text-neutral-200 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
      />
      
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};




Nobody can fix code they've never seen, on a platform with only minimal details supplied (there's no indication of browser version, or OS version affected for example), and no information about any debugging conducted (e.g. using a simulator or anything else to try and debug the JS code). Please provide a [mre] of the issue, otherwise it's unrealistic to expect anyone to provide meaningful help. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your question. Thanks./

I think the error is in the way you are using useState. Could you show me a piece of your code, where you declare your variable and where you assign the value? Have you tried to debug the value with maybe an alert()?

Thank you for your response! I have updated my question with the code snippet related to one of the input fields. Additionally, I have tested using alert() to debug the values of hotelName, and it shows the correct value when the input changes.
Let me know if you see anything that could be causing this issue!
